# How can I locate value from dropdown in C# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mstest

How Can i select value "bb" from the dropdown without using XPath. The code is

**First Dropdown**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
   <div class="form-label-group">
      <select class="custom-select">
         <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
         <option value="09">
            dd
         </option>
         <option value="08">
            ee
         </option>
         <option value="07">
            ff
         </option>                                              
      </select>
      <label for="Teacher">person</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Second DropDown**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
   <div class="form-label-group">
      <select class="custom-select">
         <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>
         <option value="01">
            aa
         </option>
         <option value="02">
            bb
         </option>
         <option value="03">
            cc
         </option>                                              
      </select>
      <label for="profile">student</label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to select value bb from second dropdown. When code runs it goes to first dropdown and cannot find value bb and fails. How can I do that?

Comment: Any particular reason you dont want to use xpath ? As you mentioned "How Can i select value "bb" from the dropdown without using XPath"

Answer (score 0):

Dom contains two dropdown with same class but different label so we can differ the dropdowns using the label

Xpath for label Teacher: `//label[@for="Teacher"]//ancestor::div//select`

Xpath for label profile: `//label[@for="profile"]//ancestor::div//select`

Now You can use [select](http://learn-automation.com/handle-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver-with-c/) class for the dropdown's

```cs
var student_drpdwn= driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//label[@for="Teacher"]//ancestor::div//select"));
var person_drpdwn= driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//label[@for="profile"]//ancestor::div//select"));
            
//Initialize class select with student_drpdwn webelement object 
           
var select_person=new Select(person_drpdwn);
var select_student=new Select(student_drpdwn);
    
//select by value
select_person.selectByValue("09");
select_student.selectByValue("01");
    
// select by text
select_person.SelectByText("dd");
select_student.SelectByText("aa");
```

Comment: it didn't work. I have updated the question with more code.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Identify your drop down
**By Xpath:**

```
var student = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='student']//ancestor::div//select"))
```

**By CSS Selector:**

```
 var student = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".custom-select:nth-of-type(2)")) # As student is second drop down on page with class name as custom-select
```

Now, create select type

```
var selectStudent = new SelectElement(student);
    
     //select by value
     selectStudent.SelectByValue("02"); 
     
     // select by text
     selectStudent.SelectByText("bb");
    
    //Select By Index. Index start at 0, so aa-0, bb-1
    selectStudent.SelectByIndex(1)
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use XPATH  for  **var student = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='student']//ancestor::div//select"))** ?

Comment: @Mehwish Are you looking to use some other locator instead of xPath ? If Yes please see updated solution. I have added css locator as wee. But please note in this particular case xPath is a better solution as i does not depend upon index as in case off CSS selecor.